# bootstrap border around a set of form-group divs that doesn't extend the entire width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap's form controls, and I want to be able to create a collapsible set of input elements, each called a section, and have the sections have a border around them.

But, the input elements inside the sections don't extend the entire width on medium or large displays, so I don't want the border to extend the entire width of the screen.

I know I can use a ::after pseudo class to make the border not extend the entire width, but the actual width needs to be responsive.

Is there a way to incorporate the bootstrap media queries in the pseudo style?

Or is there an easier way to accomplish what I want?

The other issue, is that by wrapping the sections in a div with a col-md-xx, then everything inside the div (all the rows) inherit the new width, which is also a problem.

Here is the sample code I've come up with so far:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-12 q collapse in">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email 2</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email 3</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group "></div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here is style:

```
div.q:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 9%;
    bottom: 10px;
    top: -10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;  /* or 100px */
    border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 50px; 
}
```

The width can't be set to a fixed number, either percentage or px, because on small devices the border should be 100%.

Would it just be easier to add border styling to each label / input div, rather than trying to wrap the sections in a div?